# HOW can i run "npm run dev" in cpanel i working on laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, terminal, cpanel

I working on laravel project and I need run this command in the terminal in Cpanel `npm run dev`
[image]

Comment: You'd have to install NPM, but you probably shouldn't. Typically, `npm run dev` is for your local development. You'd deploy the results of `npm run build` to the server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do have installed it? If so, try to find `/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` and run it with full path starting root. 
Like:`/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js -v`